# How Many Unique Combinations

Tags: combinations

How many unique combinations of 3 products can be made from 5 products. Repetitions are allowed (ex 1,1,1 or 1,1,2 etc)but since these are products for sale, groupings such as 1,2,3 & 3,2,1 are not allowed because both groups contain the same products and are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the number of [*multisets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) of cardinality $3$ with elements taken from a set of cardinality $5$.